# button in expandable list

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I want to create a button in the child of expandable list.

However i get Null Pointer exception.

```
btnmore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_more);
    btnmore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ParticularNewsDetail.class); <-- got problem here
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

I want to click the button to go to next activity.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of giving getBaseContext() try giving your yourclassname.this. this might work i guess..